# How can is possible to set the Content-Type in jquery Fileupload plugin for IE9 or less?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-file-upload

I am working in a rich client application and I have a problem to upload an image in IE9 and below, using the programmatic way. My code is like that:

```
$('#some-file-input-field').bind('change', function (e) {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {
        fileInput: $(this)
    });
});
```

and sending when the file is added

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.submit();
    }
});
```

but the request that IE is doing has not set the Content-type, so my server is rejecting. When I use the jquery UI with multiples files, works fine.